# Injected EntityManager null in java-ee batch job

Tags: java, java-ee-7

I am trying to use an injected entity manager to persist the output of a batch job using java-ee however the EntityManager is always null. I'm using a Maven web application running on glassfish  and schedule the job as follows.

```
@Stateless
public class Scheduler {

    @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*")
    public void runEveryMinute() {
        JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();        
        jobOperator.start("newOrderProcessJob", null);     
    }
}
```

And in my writer step

```
@Named
public class OrderWriter extends AbstractItemWriter {

    @PersistenceContext()
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void writeItems(List<Object> list){

        for (Object p : list) {                
            em.merge(p);
        }
    }
}
```

And my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
       <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_mavenproject1_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
       <jta-data-source>jdbc/directory</jta-data-source>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
       <properties>
           <property name="javax.persistence.schema-                      generation.database.action" value="create"/>
       </properties>    
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the rules precisely, but only a certain set of classes are guaranteed to be scanned and inject with that JPA annotation, and the batch artifacts are not included in that list.

So you'd have to do something else like:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_mavenproject1_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
 em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Or you could do:

```
@Named
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_mavenproject1_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU", name = "persistence/em")
public class OrderWriter extends AbstractItemWriter {

    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void open(Serializable checkpoint) {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            em = (EntityManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/em");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeItems(List<Object> list){

        for (Object p : list) {                
            em.merge(p);
        }
    }
}
```

with web.xml:

```
    <persistence-context-ref>
            <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/em</persistence-context-ref-name>
            <persistence-unit-name>com.mycompany_mavenproject1_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>
```